# How to sum array values based on keys?

Tags: php, arrays

The first array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [3] => 1
        )

)
```

I want output like

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
        )



    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [3] => 1
        )

)
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Is there always only one element inside each sub array?

Comment: I want [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
        ) as [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
        )

Comment: Why does your result have a separate sub-array for each key? Why not a single associative array with all the results?

Comment: _Happy_ you are really making us _Sad_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($input as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($result[$key])) {
            $result[$key][$key] += $value;
        } else {
            $result[$key] = array($key => $value);
        }
    }
}
$result = array_values($result); // Convert from associative array to indexed array
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a good case for [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_chunk):

```
$res = array_chunk(array_reduce($arr, function(&$current, $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($current[$key])) {
            $current[$key] = 0;
        }
        $current[$key] += $value;
    }
    return $current;
}, []), 1, true);
```

For the final result I'm using [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk); it takes an array and creates single element sub arrays of each element.